# Удаление всех символов кроме цифр

Tags: php

Добрый день, хочу удалить лишние символы из номера телефона `(099) 656-66-33`, такие как `-`, `(`, `)` и пробел, чтобы получить результат `0996566633`

Помогите создать правильную маску для фильтра.

Comment: а в чем сложность то `\D+` берет все НЕ цифры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$input = '(099) 656-66-33';
$result = preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $input);
```